# attempting to make a matching script : IndexError: string index out of range python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm pretty new to this site, but had a question about python coding. I'm trying to create a code that will search a file for a mac address and then go to another column and change the eth port. Here is what I have right now, but it is giving errors. I have things that are basically place holders till i figure out my code out. sorry for it being messy.

```
import csv

mac = (' ATTR{address}=="' + input() + '"')
print (mac)

with open('test.csv', 'rt') as f:
    #with open('results.csv', 'wt') as d:
        #writer = csv.writer(d)
    reader = dict((r[3], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(f)))
    for row in reader:
        index = reader.get(row[3])
        if mac == row[3]: # if the username shall be on column 3 (-> index 2
            message = 'Found in master list (row{})'
            print (message)
            print ('found')
        else:
            print ("oops")
```

Comment: Please also mention on which line you get the error, and what the error message is.

Comment: comment says `# if the username shall be on column 3 (-> index 2` but you are indexing at 4th position `mac == row[3]` is that correct?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\afong\Desktop\python stuff\runtest.py", line 25, in <module>
    index = reader.get(row[3])
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: the comment was mainly just to tell me how to do it I had followed someone else's code. I should probably correct it to the correct position. That's the error I get when I try to run it. I wasn't too sure what to do with the Indexing error. Thanks : )